# Third conditional from 'Sweet Home Alabama'

Tags: grammar, conditionals, cinema

I heard this 'You ever wonder what would have happened if we hadn't have gotten pregnant?'

Is this right?

Why not just '...if we hadn't gotten pregnant?'

Comment: For what it's worth, over on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/19696/32) I conjecture that this is a "formalized" orthographic representation of a set of subjunctive forms emerging in speech.

Comment: "We have gotten pregnant . . . if we hadn't done that . . . if we hadn't have gotten pregnant . . ."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because music lyrics are off-topic.

Comment: @HotL I'm confused, since there's a [lyrics tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lyrics). I thought what was off-topic are interpretations of lyrics, not constructions found in them. Perhaps a meta-question could clear this up?

Comment: @Clare - When words may be added to or removed from a phrase to satisfy the rhythm of the song it becomes off-topic here.  Also, song lyrics commonly reflect a dialect, and so may differ greatly from the queen's English.

Comment: This site is not about the Queens English is it? But I agree song requirements *may* influence lyrics. But not necessarily so. And as both a Google search and observation show, it's a construction that's gaining traction. Also see StoneyB's answer. @HotLicks

Answer (score -1):

It's a common incorrect usage; people sometimes throw in a "have" after the "had/hadn't", as is correct after the "would/wouldn't" in the other half of the sentence. Watch UK soap Eastenders for this kind of thing.

It's a mutation that has developed a sense of correctness because enough people mirror one other making it. I think it may be the rhythm of it - the extra syllable - that people find appealing, because adding the "have" there makes it equal on each half: "would have done (3 syllables), had have done (3 syllables)".

For those who think this is a one-off irrelevant thing, just try googling: a) "If you hadn't have done" and b) "If you'd have done" to see how embedded and accepted such mutations become.

Comment: It's not standard English, in other words. But saying it's incorrect when it has robust usage is prescriptionist.

Comment: 'Correct vs non-standard' is not an area I tend to debate regularly Clare, but please can you clarify your point here for.my benefit. I mean, is there no such thing as 'incorrect usage' in your understanding? Or does 'incorrect' become 'non-standard' when it becomes commonplace? Thanks

Comment: As I said,   it's incorrect in standard English. I'm not going to call a growing permutation (not your 'mutation') incorrect in an unqualified way. So,  yeah  it becomes nonstandard when it's used by a great many speakers, and it becomes standard when an even greater number of speakers find it acceptable enough to use in "standard" daily English. Usage determines grammaticality, not vice versa.

Comment: And please also clarify Clare, if I'd have said (joke!) "non-standard" instead of "incorrect", would you have agreed with the rest?

Comment: Let's put it this way, such a change would remove my downvote, probably. It's late and my brain hurts right now...

Comment: Usage determining grammaticality seems a very non-elitist down to earth pragmatic approach, but doesn't it clash with institutional bodies dedicated to language? And I wonder if no grammar is sacrosanct?

Comment: I'm honestly more interested in exploring the limits of concepts like the one you expressed so clearly than up / down points: I can't help cross-referencing to thinking on other things, however silly that is. I mean, it's kind of fascinating to think of a language changing so much (like a person, say), in unpredictable ways, and the new forms being accepted for what they are without need / desire to cling to the old. It is late :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67815/discussion-between-clare-and-mark-e-k).